# Parallel publishing of conflicting data in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, locking, publish, materialized-views

I'm working on a parallelised publishing process of an already parallelised ELT process, but there are some tables which have a different scope than our ELT, which means 2 different publish processes might end up trying to commit row locking changes at the same time. So, here's an example.

Given publishing by user, I try to end up with the following table partitioned by permission

**PERMISSIONS**

```
| permissions (PK) | uids         |
| ---------------- | ------------ |
| A                | { 10, 40 }   |
| B                | { 20, 50 }   |
| C                | { 30 }       |
```

While the most efficient format for a user based process would be something like the following:

**USER PERMISSION**

```
| uid (PK) | permission |
| -------- | ---------- |
| 10       | A          |
| 20       | B          |
| 30       | C          |
| 40       | A          |
| 50       | B          |
```

So far, the only solution I have come with is to change all of the tables in order to comply with the `ELT` scope, partition them as requested and then finally create materialised views to show whatever I want to.

Although, do materialised views have the same performance as being tables in case indexing and partitioning is kept the same?

Do you have any suggestions or potential solutions?

Comment: for some reason the tables do not render properly :/